# Is there a way to test redirects in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, redirect

We have changed our web servers. Now, I want to test if the redirects that we've put into are working properly. I've a csv file that lists all these redirects. For example, "url-prev, url-next".

Is there a way I can use JMeter to do this. I'm guessing I can use some assertions to check this.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

--Ishtiaque

Comment: Yes its possible using csv config and assertions. Question can't you rerecord it?

Comment: Yes, I can record it. I actually used a csv file for the input urls. For output or redirected urls, I manually went to those pages and figured out some keywords. Thankfully, there were only few redirect pages for 70+ input urls. I then used the csv file with two columns, one with input url and the other one with target text. I used Assertions to check if the response page has corresponding target text in them. But I was looking for a way to just check the redirects, not the response pages. Imagine, if there were 70+ unique redirect urls, it'd have been manual testing anyways. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand it correctly, but I think according to what you have, to check redirects you can use csv config like, old url, new url, text in new url <to check successful redirection>. When you run this you should be redirected to new page and the text which is present only on new page. Assertions for response can be validated for the text. If text is present in response then redirection is working else its not. If automatic redirection is enabled on webserver for old url then you dont old url,new url fields in csv, validation text should be enough. I hope you get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that you'll use:

- [CSV Data Set](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to load the CSV rows into 2 Variables url-prev,url-next

[image: CSV Config]

- [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to call the URL but NOT follow redirect

[image: HTTP Request using pre-url]

- [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) working on Response Header and checking location is ${url-next}

[image: Response assertion on location]

- [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) working on Response Code and checking it is equal to 301, 302

[image: Response assertion on code]